# Order of multiple VTK Plane Widgets

Tags: python, vtk

I am working on a VTK project where I am to have several plane widgets.
If several plane widgets pass mouse hit test at the time, the interaction starts with the one that was added to the screen the earliest . What I want to do is to start interacting with the topmost one, i.e. closest to the camera which is actually visible one the screen.

In the example below, if you want to interact with the blue plane widget and there is the red one behind, the the mouse will still interact with the red one just because it was added earlier.

I tried to use vtkPropPick, but did not come up to a solution on how to programmatically invoke interaction with the picked widget

Is there any standard/common way to approach this problem? Any other ideas? Thanks

Here is MRE

```
from vtk import *

renderer = vtkRenderer()
renderer.SetBackground(1., 1., 1.)

renderWindow = vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

renderWindowInteractor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetInteractorStyle(vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

widget1 = vtkPlaneWidget()
widget1.SetInteractor(renderWindowInteractor)
widget1.SetOrigin(0,0,0)
widget1.SetPoint1(1,0,0)
widget1.SetPoint2(0,1,0)
widget1.SetRepresentationToSurface()
widget1.SetEnabled(1)
widget1.GetPlaneProperty().SetColor(0.5,0,0)
widget1.PlaceWidget()

widget2 = vtkPlaneWidget()
widget2.SetInteractor(renderWindowInteractor)
widget2.SetOrigin(0,0,1)
widget2.SetPoint1(1,0,1)
widget2.SetPoint2(0,1,1)
widget2.SetRepresentationToSurface()
widget2.SetEnabled(1)
widget2.GetPlaneProperty().SetColor(0,0,0.5)
widget2.PlaceWidget()

renderer.ResetCamera()

renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

After tracing interactor properties three level deep I noticed that the picking manager is disabled (apparently default behavior), so simply adding the following line solved the issue

```
renderWindowInteractor.GetPickingManager().SetEnabled(True)
```